# Is there a way for algolia's distinct setting to ignore a certain value?

Tags: algolia, distinct-values

I've got some records in an aloglia index that basically look like this:

```
Book Title     | Book Author
-----------------------------
The Red Dog    |  Simon McCowell
<br>
The Blue Dog   | Unknown
<br>
The Black Dog  | Unknown
<br>
The White Dog  | Simon McCowell
```

So basically on the algolia index, I have a distinct setting on the attribute "book author". So if any of the book author values are the same, it will de duplicate the result, so that only one result for simon McCowell will show for instance. However, if there are lots of books where the author is unknown, obviously those book are not necessarily by the same order, so I don't want to remove results that have books with a value of "Unknown" for attribute "book author", is there a way or a setting where algolia can ignore the distinct setting for a certain attribute value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent deduplication on a specific value, however Algolia doesn't deduplicate when the distinct attribute is missing or `null`.

Therefore, if you format data from your example as:

```
[
    {
        "objectID": "1",
        "author": "Simon McCowell",
        "title": "The Red Dog"
    },
    {
        "objectID": "2",
        "author": null,
        "title": "The Blue Dog"
    },
    {
        "objectID": "3",
        "author": null,
        "title": "The Black Dog"
    },
    {
        "objectID": "4",
        "author": "Simon McCowell",
        "title": "The White Dog"
    }
]
```

... then querying the index with `distinct=1` will yield:

```
{
    "exhaustiveNbHits": false,
    "hits": [
        {
            "author": null,
            "objectID": "3",
            "title": "The Black Dog"
        },
        {
            "author": null,
            "objectID": "2",
            "title": "The Blue Dog"
        },
        {
            "author": "Simon McCowell",
            "objectID": "4",
            "title": "The White Dog"
        }
    ],
    "hitsPerPage": 20,
    "nbHits": 3,
    "nbPages": 1,
    "page": 0,
    "params": "distinct=1&query=",
    "processingTimeMS": 1,
    "query": ""
}
```

... which is what you want, as far as I understood.